# DT table functionality

Tags: shiny, dt

Not sure why this is happening . Can anyone help me? When the application open (by default), the modal box pops up(that is fine) when click on arrow (small arrow in the second row). But when the other date is selected (other than today), the data changes . But now if you click on small arrow, the modal box does not pop up. Not sure why? Can anyone help me?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

number_compare <- data.frame(replicate(2, sample(1:100, 10, rep=TRUE)))

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(box(width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE,
               DTOutput("example_table"),
               # actionButton("sam","sam"),
               dateInput("da","Date", value = Sys.Date(), min = Sys.Date()-1, max = Sys.Date()+1))
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  number_compare$X2[which(rownames(number_compare) == 2)] = paste(with(number_compare, X2[rownames(number_compare) == 2])," ", " ",as.character(actionLink(inputId="ang", label="", icon("caret-up"))))
 
  
  
  output$example_table <- DT::renderDT({
    
    if(input$da == Sys.Date())
    {
      datatable(
        number_compare[c(2,3:4),],
        escape = FALSE
        ,options=list(preDrawCallback=JS(
          'function() {
          Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
              drawCallback= JS(
                'function(settings) {
                Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')))
        } else {
          datatable(
            number_compare[c(2,5:6),],
            escape = FALSE
            ,options=list(preDrawCallback=JS(
              'function() {
              Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
              drawCallback= JS(
                'function(settings) {
                Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')))
        }
        
  })

  

  observeEvent(input$ang,{
    if(!is.null(input$da))
    {
      print("clicked")
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "dsd"
      ))
    }
  })
  
  
  
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Two different actionLinks have same ID.  They need to be different.  Then the dialog box pops (with another observeEvent) for the second date also.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code an edited. Even now it is not working